# C app deployment and managing dependencies in c

Tags: c, deployment, cmake, apt

I'm new to c development, but I have some experience in other modern languages .so the first thing that I found hard is dependencies and deployment, while we got Gradle, maven, NuGet and pipy and... but in c I find it a bit difficult to manage this process.
for example, I have an app that should use mongo-c-library, log4c,libarchive so basically, in my development environment, I download and unzip all of the tar files of the above libraries and then followed their instruction(usually some make stuff) and installed them in order to include them in code make the code work.
I have studied a bit about CMake but I couldn't get a clear picture of how that could actually solve the problem.
at this moment my best solution is to create an install bash script and zip all dependencies unzipped folder with that install script and then send it to the production server to deploy it.

**1.The first question is :** is it possible to just copy and past all of .so .h and etc files in /path/of/installed/dependencies/include
and /path/of/installed/dependencies/lib in the destination server libary path.

**2.if not what is the faster way?**

while I was surfing the CMake source file I found that its developers just use this package source code directly.

[image]

cmxxx contains the xxx sources and headers files.

**3.how can apt-get and Linux package manager help in the deployment process?**

2 first question was more about dependencies. imagine we have a simple c app and we want to install(build and make a useable executable file) quickly. how it can be related to .deb packages.

Comment: Take a look at cpack, especially the [DEB generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html). Recent version of apt allow you to install `.deb` packages. You can specify the dependencies that should become part of the `.deb` package info; this will result in apt installing the dependencies automatically from the repo, if set up properly.

Comment: @fabian thanks, but some( a lot) of c packages do not have apt and deb package available on the repo.

Comment: I assume you're referring to libs distributed as shared libs; you can distribute those alongside your app (`install(FILE)`) and set the rpath of your own binaries accordingly. there are probable some legal obligations though and the license of some sources may not even allow this use, so be sure to review the respective licenses, if you go this route.

Comment: Have you heard of Conan or vcpkg?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.The first question is : is it possible to just copy and past all of .so .h and etc files in /path/of/installed/dependencies/include and /path/of/installed/dependencies/lib in the destination server libary path.

Yes, technically it's possible.  That's essentially what package managers do under the hood.  However, doing that is a colossal mistake and screams bad practices.  If that's what you want then in the very least you should look into package managers to build up your own installer, which handles this sort of stuff already for you.

> 2.if not what is the faster way?

You're actually asking an entirely different question, which is: how should I distribute my code, and how do I expect users to use/deploy it?

If you want users to access your source code and build it locally, as you've mentioned cmake then you just to set up your project right as cmake already supports that usecase.

If instead you just want to distribute binaries for a platform then you'll need to build and package that code.  Again, cmake can also help you on that one, as cmake's cpack supports generating some types of packages like DEB packages used by Debian and Ubuntu, and which are handled by apt.

> 3.how can apt-get and Linux package manager help in the deployment process?

apt is designed to download and install packages from a repository.

Under the hood, apt uses DEB packages, which can be installed with `dpkg`.

If you're targeting a system that uses apt/deb, you can build DEB packages whenever you release a version to allow people to install their software.

You can also go a step beyond and release your DEB packages in a [Personal Package Archive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas).

Comment: Caveats: (1) .deb packages are specific to Debian-family Linuxes, such as Ubuntu.  Other Linuxes have other packaging formats, including, but not limited to, RPM. (2) One does not, generally, include all the external dependencies in one's package.  Instead, one defines that package's dependencies on other packages providing those dependencies, and lets the package manager figure out what to do.

Comment: Debian-derived distros represent close to half the installbase of linux distros, with Ubuntu alone representing about 30% of all linux installations.  The requester also refers specifically to apt. Having said that, CPack also supports RPM.

Comment: @RAM i  have checked CPack a bit,there are some option that we can be used for libraries which are available on repo.but what about library which are not in repo. let me make it clear with an example. for example, imagine that we have a simple main.c code file which use the method in libarchive ,which are available after  downloading and installing the libarchive source so after we compile main.c code and we have a binary executable output file which is runnable in my environment .

Comment: @RAM continue above:
and not runnable in any other which libarchive is not installed with that procedure so what to do?

Comment: @SinaGz if your project has dependencies that are not automatically fulfilled then you need to provide them yourself.   One option is to bundle them in your own package so that it's a standalone installer.  This is pretty trivial if you can statically link a library.  The next best thing is to package the dependency yourself.  The key take is that you have the responsibility of fulfilling the dependencies you've decided to adopt.  If a OS does not provide them then you need to fill in the blank yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically NOT download and install source packages. Instead you should generally rely on the libraries and development packages of the distribution. When building your own package you would typically just reference the packages or files that your package is dependent on. Then you build your own package and you're done. Upon installation of your package, all dependencies will automatically be resolved in an appropriate order.

What exactly needs to be done is dependent on the package management system, but generally the above statements apply. Be advised, package management apparently is pretty hard, because so many 3rd party developers screw it up.